# Removing Characters From SQL String (Search)

Tags: sql, search, replace

Should be a pretty simple one today. I have a column with a list of contracts:

[image]

As you see, some contracts have a  "-...." at the end. I need to removed this and any character after this (see desired output). Unfortunately, it's not just 1 character (could be multiple/differenct #s). So I imagine it's going to be a right/len/search combo.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is it always the left 7 characters that you are wanting?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Desired output", is a SQL column? Do you just using SQL or with an application in java, c#, etc...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Anyone else want to be constructive besides FreshPrince? I'm using SQL, the character limit changes but there's always at ...-.... I tried using Left(A.ContractNumber, charindex('-', A.ContractNumber, charindex('-', A.ContractNumber) + 1) - 1) but I kept getting this error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contracts all have the same form, the following is almost standard SQL for doing what you want:

```
select (case when CTNumber like '%-%-%'
             then left(CTNumber, 7)
             else CTNumber
        end) as DesiredOutput
from t
```

The `like` syntax is standard, the `case` is standard, and most databases have a `left()` function.  This does assume that the form of the CTNumber is such that you always want the first seven characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `patindex` to confirm the presence of two dashes.  With a double `charindex`, you can then return the part of the string before the second dash:

```
select  case 
        when patindex('%-%-%', col1) > 0 then
            left(col1, charindex('-', col1, charindex('-', col1) + 1) - 1)
        else col1
        end as col1
from    dbo.YourTable
```